# Why does dot product give correct angle, but cross product does not?

Tags: angle, vector-lattices

Question:
The primitive lattice vectors for a body-centered cubic lattice are given by $\vec a_1 =\frac{a}{2}(1,1,-1)$ , $\vec a_2 =\frac{a}{2}(-1,1,1)$ , $ \vec a_3 =\frac{a}{2}(1,-1,1)$. Calculate the angle between two of the primitive lattice vectors in bcc?

When calculating the angle, I have used the formula $\vec a_1 \cdot \vec a_2 = |a_1||a_2|cos\theta$ which gives me the correct answer $109.47° $.

My question is, why don't I get the correct answer when using the cross product instead of the dot product? When I use this formula $|a_1 \times a_2|=|a_1||a_2|sin\theta$ I get the incorrect angle $70.53°$.

I also noticed that when I take $180°-70.53°$, I get the correct answer. Why is this?

Comment: You took an absolute value...that caused you to pick up a false solution.

Comment: $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin\theta$.

Comment: To drive the previous point home, cosine is injective on $[0,\pi]$, while sine is not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$\cos \theta$ can be negative if $\theta \in \left(\frac {\pi}{2},\pi\right)$

But in case of sine,  it is positive in this interval too(i.e $\sin(\pi-\theta) =\sin \theta)$) thus the angle isn't precisely correct